# what does python think about B > A

Tags: python

comparison of letter of alphabet

```
if "b" > "a":
    print("greater")
```

is python going to evaluate them in order they appear in alphabet?
what if i evaluate a letter like a with a number?
will it be according to ASCII?

Comment: yes they are compared based on ASCII values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here are a few examples:

[image]

And for your convenience, the ASCII table:

[image]